# mongodb: unable to remove docs from array input

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections where one holds the data and other holds the _id values which has to be removed from first collection.

```
db.Mapper.count()
// Gives me count of 600k docs
However, both the below queries are unable to remove docs from the first collection
db.zeroDimFacts.remove({_id: {$in:[db.Mapper.distinct("IDI")]})
// nRemoved: 0
db.zeroDimFacts.remove({"_id": {$in: [db.Mapper.distinct("IDI")]}}, {writeConcern: {w:"majority", wtimeout:10000}})
// nRemoved: 0
```

There are more than 300k docs matching in both the collections.
Can someone find out what is preventing the deletion of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query `db.Mapper.distinct("IDI")` already returns an array as a result so there is no need to wrap the result again in another array, just use the result directly as:

```
db.Mapper.count();
// Gives me count of 600k docs
// remove docs from the first collection
var mapperIds = db.Mapper.distinct("IDI");
db.zeroDimFacts.remove({"_id": { "$in": mapperIds } });
```